# Mapping extra properties in a lookup table and EF

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I have the following many-to-many relationship set up in my db.

[image: table example]

Mapped using Code-First EF; A `Ticket` has an `ICollection` of `Branch` and vice versa.

This all works fine but now I need to make a significant change since the spec has been fleshed out.

Originally a single `Ticket` could be marked as `IsRead` but that, as a concept, only really works when the `Ticket` is allocated to a single branch. What I need to do is say that a `Ticket` has been read at each individual `Branch`.

Now my first thought is that I should change the relational table `BranchTickets` so that it has an Identity column and the `IsRead` property thus creating a one-to-many relationship but I don't know then how to map the two foreign keys using the Code-First Api.

Would this be the right approach, and if so how would I go about ensuring EF maps the tables appropriately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a `Ticket` can only be deemed *read* at `Branch` level, then I would say all you need to do is remove the `IsRead` property from `Ticket` and move it to `BranchTickets`.

This means each individual ticket can be associated with multiple branches which can have different *read* states.

> how would I go about ensuring EF maps the tables appropriately

This is a change you would need to make at DB level, you can then update your EF model.

Comment: Could you please clarify what changes I would need to make to the models themselves? I've updated the db and my edmx but I'm now stuck at the code-first part.

Comment: In VS, if you double click your EDMX file it should open up in the designer view. Right click anywhere in the model and you should see an "Update model from Database" option. You may need to manually delete the old `IsRead` property from your Ticket model manually I am not sure if it automatically removes fields.

Comment: I meant with the POCO classes themselves. I got it though thanks.

Comment: @JamesSouth Oops sorry I just read your first comment and you had said "*I've updated the db **and** my edmx*" (I missed the and part!).

Comment: Cheers. Your original comment actually put me on the track of using the POCO generator to generate new classes since that was where I got properly stuck.